# Is there a word for when you run into someone and both of you try to avoid each other and fail, repeatedly?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idiom-requests

It has most certainly happened to all of us at least once: Two people walking along the same narrow pathway in opposite directions walk into each other.

There is room for both to pass each other, but person A shifts to their left to avoid B, and B shifts to their right (i.e., A's left) in order to do the same thing, so they're still on a collision course.

They both realize the mistake and they both try to correct it by moving to the opposite side they did before, so the problem persists.

Rinse and repeat 3 or 4 times until one of the parties realizes: "I'll stick to the left (or right) no matter what, and let *him* pick *the other* side!", in a sort of perverse human feedback loop.

**Is there a word or idiom to describe this situation?**

Comment: I seriously doubt there is, but want to make sure.

Comment: also duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32246/153217

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's something I've always known as the [sidewalk shuffle](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sidewalk+shuffle):

> the awkward dance that results when two people approach each other
>   from opposite directions, each attempts to move out of the other's
>   way, and both end up moving in the same direction. Often followed by
>   further ungainly movement, apologies, and awkward laughter.

[Urban Dictionary]

Comment: A google search gives several references besides your Urban Dictionary link, so it must be legit. Here, have your tick! (walks towards you by the left)

Comment: All the other links I saw seemed to point to card tricks, lol.  Oh well, no shuffling here, coz I go left too.

Comment: There was a rage comic. Also, this: http://www.octopuspie.com/2012-04-13/530-the-octopus-pie-guide-to-preventing-sidewalk-shuffle/

Comment: Hi, mcalex. Linking just a website is not encouraged in this community as your link can become invalid if the linked page changes. I edited your post and please see if it is OK and try to follow the format.

Comment: Not sure if Urban dictionary is a valid enough dictionary to be referenced here for answers

Comment: I know people make this complaint, I feel unreasonably, against Wikipedia. But Urban Dictionary is almost literally the monkeys and typewriters metaphor.